# How can I random key in loop?

Tags: php, html

My code is like this :

```
<?php
    $colors = array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($colors as $color) {
?>
        <div class="<?php echo $i==0 ? 'active' : '' ?>">
            <?php echo $color.'-'.$i; ?>
        </div>
<?php   
        $i++;   
    }
?>
```

When code above executed, the first class will active

I want to make it to be random

So when executed, Any class can be active

For example when I run, class on first div will active
When I run again, the class on the third div is active.
So it's random

How can I do it?

Comment: $rand =rand(0,count($colors)-1);   and  <div class="<?=($i== $rand)? 'active' : '' ?>">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `rand(0,count($colors)-1)` it will give one number between your limit

```
    <?php
    $colors = array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
    $i = 0;
    $rand =rand(0,count($colors)-1);
    foreach ($colors as $color) {
    ?>
        <div class="<?=($i== $rand)? 'active' : '' ?>">
            <?php echo $color.'-'.$i; ?>
        </div>
   <?php   
        $i++;   
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$colors      = ["a" => "red", "b" => "green", "c" => "blue", "d" => "yellow"];
$i           = 0;
$activeIndex = array_rand($colors);
foreach ($colors as $key => $color) {
    echo "<div class=\"" . (($key == $activeIndex) ? 'active' : '') . "\">$color-$i</div>";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

It uses php's [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function to get the key of the array to select as active.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will return random values.

```
$colors = array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$colors = array_rand($colors, 1);
echo $colors;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the rand() function.

```
$random = rand(0,5)
```

This would return a random int between 0 and 5. For more information google rand() php

Answer (score 0):

Either you use

```
array_rand($colors, 1)
```

or you use

```
mt_rand(0, count($colors));
```

See manual for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php & http://php.net/mt_rand